# Bash capturing output of find with exclusion into the While loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, find

I made a script that looks for the content of a folder recursively, excluding some paths, then asks for an action to take on each line of the results.

The find command on its own is working fine and exclude paths as expected. It looks something like that:

```
$SOURCE="FOLDER/"
$EXCLUDESTRING="! -path \"FOLDER/*/.svn/*\" ! -path \"FOLDER/uploads/*\" ! -path \"FOLDER/ai-cache/*\""

find "$SOURCE"* $EXCLUDESTRING # uploads and ai-cache folders are not included in the results
```

But when I pipe the result to the While loop it does not consider the exclusions.

```
find "$SOURCE"* $EXCLUDESTRING -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file_1
do
    echo $file_1 # uploads and ai-cache folders are included in the results
    if statement ...
    more commands ...
done
```

I want to mention that the goal is to find the desired files and folders and process them instantaneously without using an array.

---

UPDATE

---

For those who are interested in my script (Step by step unidirectional sync) or could test (it will be very appreciated) Here is a more detailed copy:

```
#!/bin/bash
excludepath=( "*/.svn/*" "uploads/*" "design/*" "ai-cache/*" )
bold=`tput bold`
normal=`tput sgr0`
validsource="false"
while [ "$validsource" == "false" ]
do
    echo ""
    echo "Specify project to compare :"
    echo -n "/home/myaccount/public_html/projects/"
    read -e project
    project=`echo "$project" | sed -e "s/\/*$//" `
    projectpath="/home/myaccount/public_html/projects/$project"
    source="$(readlink -f $projectpath)/"
    if [ -d "$source" ];then
        validsource="true"
    else
        echo "The working copy cannot be found ($projectpath)."
    fi
done
echo "Compare project with folder :"
read -e target
excludestring=""
for i in "${excludepath[@]}"
do
    excludestring="$excludestring ! -path \"$source$i\""
done
echo ""
echo "______________________________________________"
echo ""
echo "COMPARISON IN PROGRESS ..."
echo "______________________________________________"
echo ""
echo "List of paths excluded from the comparison: ${excludepath[@]}"
echo "Executed command : find \"$source\"* $excludestring"
echo ""
liveexclude=()
find "$source"* $excludestring -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file_1
do
    file=$( echo "$file_1" | sed "s,$source,,g" ) # Strip base path
    file_2=$( echo "$file_1" | sed "s,$source,$target,g" ) # Getting file path in $target
    dir=$( dirname "$file_2" | sed "s,$target,,g" )
    dir_1=$( dirname "$file_1" )
    dir_2=$( dirname "$file_2" )
    #Check for live excluded folders
    process="true"
    for i in "${liveexclude[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $file_1 == "$i"* ]]
        then
            process="false"
            break
        fi
    done

    if [ "$process" == "true" ];then
        if [ -d "$file_1" ];then
            if [ ! -d "$file_2" ] # Checking if sub-dir exists in $target
            then
                while [ "$confirm" != "y" ] && [ "$confirm" != "n" ]
                do
                    echo ""
                    echo "${bold}Folder${normal} \"$file\" doesn't exist."
                    echo -n "Would you like to ${bold}create it and its entire contents${normal} ? (y/n) "
                    read -e confirm </dev/tty
                done
                if [ "$confirm" == "y" ];then
                    mkdir -p $file_2                                                # Creating if sub-dir missing
                    cp -r "$file_1/"* "$file_2"
                fi
                confirm=""

                liveexclude+=("$file_2")
            fi
        else
            if [ -f "$file_1" ];then
                if [ -f "$file_2" ]                                                 # Checking if file exists in $target
                then
                    cksum_file_1=$( cksum "$file_1" | cut -f 1 -d " " )             # Get cksum of file in $source
                    cksum_file_2=$( cksum "$file_2" | cut -f 1 -d " " )             # Get cksum of file in $target

                    if [ $cksum_file_1 -ne $cksum_file_2 ]                          # Check if cksum matches
                    then
                        while [ "$confirm" != "y" ] && [ "$confirm" != "n" ]
                        do
                            if [ "$file_1" -nt "$file_2" ]
                            then
                                echo ""
                                echo "${bold}File${normal} \"$file\" is not updated."
                                echo -n "Would you like to ${bold}replace${normal} it ? (y/n) "
                            else
                                echo ""
                                echo "${bold}File${normal} \"$file\" was modified."
                                echo "${bold}CAUTION${normal}: The file \"$file_2\" is newer than the file \"$file_1\""
                                echo -n "Would you still ${bold}overwrite${normal} it ? (y/n) "
                            fi
                            read -e confirm </dev/tty
                        done
                        if [ "$confirm" == "y" ];then
                            cp "$file_1" "$file_2"                                      # Copy if cksum mismatch
                        fi
                        confirm=""
                    fi
                else
                    while [ "$confirm" != "y" ] && [ "$confirm" != "n" ]
                    do
                        echo ""
                        echo "${bold}File${normal} \"$file\" doesn't exist."
                        echo -n "Would you like to ${bold}copy${normal} it ? (y/n) "
                        read -e confirm </dev/tty
                    done
                    if [ "$confirm" == "y" ];then
                        cp "$file_1" "$file_2"                                          # Copy if file does not exist.
                    fi
                    confirm=""
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

PS. We use this script for applying new changes on an existing project if a detailed check is required.

Comment: I don't believe that the first `find` command as written will work, because it includes stray double quotes which will cause the `-path` condition to fail, as they will in your second example as well. Of course you only say that the line looks "something like" what you put in the question; I suspect that it is the differences from "something like" that cause the first line to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your commands in a string, but in an array. And don't use a dollar in the *left-hand side of an assignment* (we're not in Perl/PHP). Oh, and avoid using upper case variable names. It looks ugly; it seems you're shouting the variable's name; but more seriously it might clash with reserved names (like `PATH`, `LINES`, `GROUPS`, `USERS`, etc.); if you stick to lower case variable names, you're on the safe side (and it's prettier!).

```
source=FOLDER/
excludeary=( \! -path "FOLDER/*/.svn/*" \! -path "FOLDER/uploads/*" \! -path "FOLDER/ai-cache/*" )

find "$source" "${excludeary[@]}" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file_1
do
    echo "$file_1" # uploads and ai-cache folders are included in the results
    if statement ...
    more commands ...
done
```

---

**Edit.** Here's a small example:

```
$ mkdir Test
$ cd Test
$ mkdir -p {excl,incl}/{1,2}
$ touch {excl,incl}/{1,2}/{a,b}
$ tree
.
|-- excl
|   |-- 1
|   |   |-- a
|   |   `-- b
|   `-- 2
|       |-- a
|       `-- b
`-- incl
    |-- 1
    |   |-- a
    |   `-- b
    `-- 2
        |-- a
        `-- b

6 directories, 8 files
$ source=~/Test
$ excludeary=( \! -path "$source/excl/*" )
$ find "$source" "${excludeary[@]}"
/home/gniourf/Test
/home/gniourf/Test/excl
/home/gniourf/Test/incl
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/1
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/1/a
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/1/b
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2/a
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2/b
```

That's how `! -path` works. See, you still have the `/home/gniourf/Test/excl` folder (but not its children). Maybe you want `-prune` instead:

```
$ pruneary=( \! \( -type d -name excl -prune \) )
$ find "$source" "${pruneary[@]}"
/home/gniourf/Test
/home/gniourf/Test/incl
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/1
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/1/a
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/1/b
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2/a
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2/b
```

Or to exclude all the `1` directories together with the `excl` directory:

```
$ excludeary=( \! \( -type d \( -name excl -o -path '*/1' \) -prune \) )
$ find "$source" "${excludeary[@]}"
/home/gniourf/Test
/home/gniourf/Test/incl
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2/a
/home/gniourf/Test/incl/2/b
```

Comment: Thank you @gniourf_gniourf for all the useful notes. I put the dollar in the left-hand side negligently here. I tested your script and oddly, I still can not eliminate unwanted paths even this way!

Comment: Thanks again for all the details. I'm aware I have the excluded folder but not its content in my case and it is not a problem. I've been searching the Web for 2 days and I still believe something is wrong when I try to capture the find results. I gave more details about my question so may be you can check it out.

Comment: Hi @gniourf_gniourf, that's it! Putting commands in an array resolved the problem. It didn't work for me in the first try because my `source` variable had a trailing slash. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

All of the necessary exclusions worked for me when I removed all of the double quotes and put everything in single quotes:

```
EXCLUDESTRING='! -path FOLDER/*/.svn/* ! -path \"FOLDER/uploads/* ! -path FOLDER/ai-cache/*'
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Wheeler, I updated my question with more details on how I define the `excludestring`variable